# How to divide a sphere into many equally sized triangular tiles?

Tags: spheres, tiling, tessellations

I am inspired by [spherical tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polyhedron):

[image]

How do you take a sphere, such as one roughly the size of earth, which has a radius (assuming perfect sphere) of 6,356,000 meters, and divide it into triangular tiles (like the image above) which are within some x square meters in area (say 10 meters), and which are all the same area?

Technically, I would like to eventually then have some code be able to reference these "triangular areas" somehow, so if you know of some code to do this that will be even better, but really all that I am asking is for the math needed to divide a sphere into evenly sized triangular tiles of a certain size, like the image above.

Comment: Perhaps it is [more complicated than I thought](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/indexing-the-sphere-with-the-hierarchical-triangular-mesh)? [Other related](https://www.redblobgames.com/x/1640-hexagon-tiling-of-sphere/) as well.

Comment: I guess an "icosahedral [geodesic polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_polyhedron)" would be the perfect solution, now just how to figure out how to divide it into small enough chunks, or something along those lines. I imagine you can't get exactly 10m area, but perhaps you can get some known order of magnitude areas which are all equal? How to do that if it simplifies things?

Comment: It turns out [H3](https://h3geo.org/) from Uber solves the "icosahedral geodesic polyhedron" problem, it's just a bit of a mystery how they did it! I would still like to know how to do a similar thing for the triangles.

Answer (score 1):

The "icosahedral geodesic polyhedron" problem simplifies your original problem by removing the restriction that all triangular areas be equal.

The area of a spherical triangle is given by the formula A = r²(s-π), where r is the radius of the sphere and s is the sum of the internal angles in radians. When six triangles meet at a vertex the internal angle created is 60°, but when five triangles meet at a vertex the internal angle created is 72°. And there are twelve such vertices where five triangles meet on an icosahedron.

Divide each face of an icosahedron into T equilateral triangles; the resultant geodesic polyhedron, projected onto a sphere, gives a spherical polyhedron.

Letting T = 4ᴺ allows us the use of a simple iterative algorithm to generate the triangles:

1. Subdivide each triangle into four smaller congruent triangles.
2. Repeat step 1, N-1 times.

For indexing algorithm:

1. Align one of the icosahedron vertices with the north pole and another with the south pole.
2. Label the 20 original triangles (eg. A-T).
3. In each round of subdivision we append to the end one of four labels (eg. 1-4) according to the following pattern:

   A. The central triangle is given label 1

   B. The triangle that has a vertex pointed towards a pole is given label 2

   C. The remaining two triangles are given labels 3 and 4 in clockwise
   order.

   ```
    Note that each pair of appended labels is simply convertable to hex:
        11 = 0
        14 = 3
        41 = c
        44 = f
   ```
4. Append a termination label (eg. z).

Thus, D-2d410b6d2d2dz is a 900 sq.cm. section, and D-z is roughly the size of Canada.

(To get areas ≤ 10 sq.m., N > 19.)